# Is fwrite faster than WriteFile in windows?

Tags: c++, performance, winapi, file-io, fwrite

I have always thought that WriteFile is more efficient than fwrite, because fwrite calls down to WriteFile internally, but the following test code show me that fwrite is faster significantly than WriteFile.

fwrite costs 2 milliseconds while WriteFile need 27000(FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL), both flushes after every write call. If I call WriteFile with FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, and comment the FlushFileBuffers(wfile) line , WriteFile will be faster, it costs 800.

So Is it really that fwrite calls down to WriteFile? What makes such a huge difference? How does fwrite work internally? How can I write data to file with API more efficiently than fwrite?(unbufferd, synchronous).

```
   #include <Windows.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
     FILE* cfile = fopen("file1.txt", "w");
     HANDLE wfile = CreateFile("file2.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 
           /*FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL*/FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, NULL);
     DWORD written = 0;

     DWORD start_time, end_time;
     char * text = "test message ha ha ha ha";
     int size = strlen(text);
     int times = 999;

     start_time = timeGetTime();
     for(int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
       fwrite(text, 1, size, cfile);
       fflush(cfile);
     }
     end_time = timeGetTime();
     std::cout << end_time - start_time << '\n';

     start_time = timeGetTime();
     for(int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
         WriteFile(wfile, text, size, &written, NULL);
         //FlushFileBuffers(wfile);
     }
     end_time = timeGetTime();
     std::cout << end_time - start_time << std::endl;

     system("pause");
     return 0;
   }
```

**Update:**
Thanks for the answers, here is the answer:
see VS directory\VS\crt\src\fflush.c:

```
    //fflush.c
    int __cdecl _fflush_nolock (FILE *str) {
        //irrelevant codes
        if (str->_flag & _IOCOMMIT) {
                return (_commit(_fileno(str)) ? EOF : 0);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

so here is a _IOCOMMIT flag, then see ...\src\fdopen.c

```
    FILE * __cdecl _tfdopen (int filedes, const _TSCHAR *mode) {
      //irrelevant codes
        while(*++mode && whileflag)
          switch(*mode) {
      //...
              case _T('c'):
                if (cnflag)
                    whileflag = 0;
                else {
                    cnflag = 1;
                    fileflag |= _IOCOMMIT;
                }
               break;
     //...
    }
```

_tfopen is called by fopen internally, refer to the documents of fopen, I find this:

"
mode:
'c'

Enable the commit flag for the associated filename so that the contents of the file buffer are written directly to disk if either fflush or _flushall is called."
So, _commit is called only if 'c' flag is set when calling fopen.

the _commit function eventually calls FlushFileBuffers.

Besides these, I find that when I write only a few data to file(not exceeds the buffer size), if fwrite without fflush, the text will not be wrritten apparently, while for API, after WriteFile even if I don't call FlushFileBuffers, when I open the file(program is in Sleep), the content is written to file automatically, that was one of the reasons why I was confused about flush , this operation may be done by OS, WriteFile copies data to system cache, and its file buffer is managed by OS, so it's resonable that fflush() only calls WriteFile internally without real flushing, system knows when to flush them, maybe when file handle is closed or when another I/O access to this file is occured.
So I modified the benchmark as this:

```
      start_time = timeGetTime();
for(int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
    fwrite(text, 1, size, cfile);
    fflush(cfile);
}
end_time = timeGetTime();
std::cout << end_time - start_time << '\n';

start_time = timeGetTime();
for(int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
    WriteFile(wfile, text, size, &written, NULL);
}
end_time = timeGetTime();
std::cout << end_time - start_time << std::endl;
```

the result is 
times:99999
fwrite:217
WriteFile:171

So, in conclusion, to speed up API file writting operation:

1. Do not call FlushFileBuffers explicitly， data in system cache will be flushed to disk when needed.
2. Get a buffer for WriteFile, just as fwrite does, because API call cost more time than simply memcpy, call WriteFile when buffer is filled up.

Comment: What do you mean by efficiency? The application is more responsive or that the time between API call and data being on the medium be as sort as possible?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `GENERIC_ALL`?

Comment: @lego I mean the speed of writting call

Comment: @Mehrdad GENERIC_ALL is not valid here, I tried GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE， 800+ milliseconds

Comment: Try changing the share mode `FILE_SHARE_READ` to 0.  This will open the file exclusively which may have an impact.

Comment: @Frahm In this case I suggest you use WriteFile asynchronously (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using a tool like [Process Monitor (procmon)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Sysinternals, you'll see that the call to `fflush()` isn't doing the same thing as `FlushFileBuffers(wfile)` (or the `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` flag to `CreateFile()`).

`fwrite()` will write the data to a buffer until that buffer fills, which will cause it to send the data in the buffer to `WriteFile()` call.  When you call `fflush()` all that happens is that the data currently in the buffer is passed to a call to `WriteFile()` - `fflush()` doesn't call `FlushFileBuffers()`:

```
1:21:32.9391534 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file1.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 24
1:21:32.9392200 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file1.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 24, Length: 24
1:21:32.9392340 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file1.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 48, Length: 24
1:21:32.9392436 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file1.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 72, Length: 24
1:21:32.9392526 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file1.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 96, Length: 24
1:21:32.9392623 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file1.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 120, Length: 24
```

For comparison, here's an example of a trace from the `fwrite()` loop without the `fflush()` call:

```
1:27:28.5675034 AM  test.exe    3140    WriteFile   C:\temp\file1.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 1,024
1:27:28.5676098 AM  test.exe    3140    WriteFile   C:\temp\file1.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 1,024, Length: 1,024
1:27:28.5676399 AM  test.exe    3140    WriteFile   C:\temp\file1.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 2,048, Length: 1,024
1:27:28.5676651 AM  test.exe    3140    WriteFile   C:\temp\file1.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 3,072, Length: 1,024
```

And here's a snippet of the trace from the `WriteFile()` loop (with the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` flag and explicit call to `FlushFileBuffers()` - it just makes what's happening easier to see in the trace since the `FlushFileBuffers()` call is shown in the trace instead of just showing as a second 4KB `WriteFile()` call).

```
1:21:29.0068503 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 24, Priority: Normal
1:21:29.0069197 AM  test.exe    6132    FlushBuffersFile    C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS 
1:21:29.0069517 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 4,096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
1:21:29.0087574 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 24, Length: 24
1:21:29.0087798 AM  test.exe    6132    FlushBuffersFile    C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS 
1:21:29.0088087 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 4,096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
1:21:29.0102260 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 48, Length: 24
1:21:29.0102428 AM  test.exe    6132    FlushBuffersFile    C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS 
1:21:29.0102701 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 4,096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
1:21:29.0113444 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 72, Length: 24
1:21:29.0113602 AM  test.exe    6132    FlushBuffersFile    C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS 
1:21:29.0113848 AM  test.exe    6132    WriteFile   C:\temp\file2.txt   SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 4,096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
```

So the reason that your benchmark shows a severe disadvantage to the `WriteFile()` loop is simply because you have about a thousand calls to `FlushFileBuffers()` that aren't in the `fwrite()` loop.

Comment: You're right, in fdopen.c, there is a switch case 'c', fileflag |= _IOCOMMIT; which means" 
Enable the commit flag for the associated filename so that the contents of the file buffer are written directly to disk if either fflush or _flushall is called."-From MSDN

Comment: Buffering speeds up large numbers of small writes. That's why it's used in high-level I/O libraries.

Answer (score 6):

If properly setup, `WriteFile()` *can* be more efficient than `fwrite()`. `WriteFile()` allows you to fine-tailor the conditions it uses to when performing the IO request you're issuing.

For example, you can bypass the intermediate buffered IO subsystem and pull directly from *your* data pointer as if it were the intermediate IO buffer, therefore removing a significant middle-man. The setup, however, is somewhat restrictive. Your data pointer must lay on a byte boundary equivalent to the sector size of the volume being written to. No such facility exists with `fwrite()` for hopefully obvious reasons. Windows API enthusiasts (circa J. Richter and his brethren) are big fans of twiddling with such usages of `WriteFile()` to squeeze every last drop out of their Windows program IO performance.

And if you're wondering why people aren't `WriteFile()` love-children I can assure you many people are, but *none* of them are the least-bit interested in portable code. The ones that are (or just aren't *that* concerned about it (what was it Knuth said about premature optimization..?), choose standard facilities like `fwrite()`.

If you're *really* interested in the MSVCRT-implementation of `fwrite()` and how it does what it does, check out the source. It is shipped with every version of VC++ Standard or greater (perhaps not Express; I've never checked).

Comment: Nice answer, +1 here - although I question your use of "love children" :)

Comment: @HerrJoebob LOL. Sometimes it just comes to me. =P

Comment: The question is asking why `WriteFile()` appears to be so much *less* efficient than `fwrite()`. The example is hardly an advertisement for using `WriteFile()` to squeeze every last drop of I/O performance.

Comment: I'm a `WriteFile` love child and proud ;)  Uses of it can be found in the visual studio directory\VC\crt\src\write.c (also see, fwrite.c, open.c and fopen.c).

Comment: @Steve I hope that isn't taken  wrong, if I'm writing Windows code, and I *know* it always will be Windows code for life, we have the same parents =P (or at least one...)

Comment: @WhozCraig it was taken in the humour you intended :)  It's nice to see a post that doesn't insist on writing portable code when no requirement exists for it.

Comment: Thanks, I have referd to the the source codes, and it really helped.