# Why is C <stdio.h> FILE* fread() faster than Win32 ReadFile()?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, file-io

Comparing reading files using the following three techniques:

1. C `<stdio.h>` `FILE*`
2. Win32 `CreateFile()`/`ReadFile()`
3. Win32 memory mapping

I noted that #1 is faster than #2, and #3 is the fastest.

e.g. Sorted from the fastest to the slowest, for processing a 900MB test file, I got these results:

> Win32 memory mapping: 821.308 ms
>
> C  file (FILE*): 1779.83 ms
>
> Win32 file (CreateFile): 3649.67 ms

Why is the C `<stdio.h>` technique faster than Win32 `ReadFile()` access? I'd expect raw Win32 APIs to have *less* overhead than CRT. What am I missing here?

Compilable test C++ source code follows.

---

**EDIT**

I repeated the tests with 4KB read buffers and using **three** different files (with the same content) to avoid *caching* effects that could distort performance measurements, and now the results are as expected.
For example, for a file of circa 400 MB the results are:

1. **Win32 memory mapping**: 305.908 ms
2. Win32 file (CreateFile): 451.402 ms
3. C  file (FILE*): 460.579 ms

---

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Test file reading using C FILE*, Win32 CreateFile and Win32 memory mapping.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                      Performance (speed) measurement
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

long long counter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return li.QuadPart;
}

long long frequency()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
    return li.QuadPart;
}

void print_time(const long long start, const long long finish,
    const char * const s)
{
    std::cout << s << ": " << (finish - start) * 1000.0 / frequency() << " ms\n";
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                      RAII handle wrappers
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct c_file_traits
{
    typedef FILE* type;

    static FILE* invalid_value()
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    static void close(FILE* f)
    {
        fclose(f);
    }
};

struct win32_file_traits
{
    typedef HANDLE type;

    static HANDLE invalid_value()
    {
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    static void close(HANDLE h)
    {
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
};

struct win32_handle_traits
{
    typedef HANDLE type;

    static HANDLE invalid_value()
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    static void close(HANDLE h)
    {
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
};

template <typename Traits>
class handle
{
public:
    typedef typename Traits::type type;

    handle()
        : _h(Traits::invalid_value())
    {
    }

    explicit handle(type h)
        : _h(h)
    {
    }

    ~handle()
    {
        close();
    }

    bool valid() const
    {
        return (_h != Traits::invalid_value());
    }

    type get() const
    {
        return _h;
    }

    void close()
    {
        if (valid())
            Traits::close(_h);

        _h = Traits::invalid_value();
    }

    void reset(type h)
    {
        if (h != _h)
        {
            close();
            _h = h;
        }
    }


private: // Ban copy
    handle(const handle&);
    handle& operator=(const handle&);

private:
    type _h;    // wrapped raw handle
};

typedef handle<c_file_traits> c_file_handle;
typedef handle<win32_file_traits> win32_file_handle;
typedef handle<win32_handle_traits> win32_handle;


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//              File reading tests using various techniques
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

unsigned long long count_char_using_c_file(const std::string& filename, const char ch)
{
    unsigned long long char_count = 0;

#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4996) // fopen use is OK
    c_file_handle file(fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb"));
#pragma warning(pop)

    if (!file.valid())
        throw std::runtime_error("Can't open file.");

    std::vector<char> read_buffer(4*1024); // 4 KB
    bool has_more_data = true;
    while (has_more_data)
    {
        size_t read_count = fread(read_buffer.data(), 1, read_buffer.size(), file.get());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < read_count; i++)
        {
            if (read_buffer[i] == ch)
                char_count++;
        }

        if (read_count < read_buffer.size())
            has_more_data = false;
    }

    return char_count;
}


unsigned long long count_char_using_win32_file(const std::string& filename, const char ch)
{
    unsigned long long char_count = 0;

    win32_file_handle file(::CreateFileA(
        filename.c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        nullptr,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        nullptr
        )
        );
    if (!file.valid())
        throw std::runtime_error("Can't open file.");

    std::vector<char> read_buffer(4*1024); // 4 KB
    bool has_more_data = true;
    while (has_more_data)
    {
        DWORD read_count = 0;
        if (!ReadFile(file.get(), read_buffer.data(), read_buffer.size(), &read_count, nullptr))
            throw std::runtime_error("File read error using ReadFile().");

        for (size_t i = 0; i < read_count; i++)
        {
            if (read_buffer[i] == ch)
                char_count++;
        }

        if (read_count < sizeof(read_buffer))
            has_more_data = false;
    }

    return char_count;
}


// Memory-map a file.
class file_map
{
public:
    explicit file_map(const std::string& filename)
        : _view(nullptr), _length(0)
    {
        _file.reset(::CreateFileA(
            filename.c_str(),
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            nullptr,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            nullptr));
        if (!_file.valid())
            return;

        LARGE_INTEGER file_size;
        if (!GetFileSizeEx(_file.get(), &file_size))
            return;

        if (file_size.QuadPart == 0)
            return;

        _mapping.reset(::CreateFileMapping(
            _file.get(), nullptr,
            PAGE_READONLY,
            0,
            0,
            nullptr)
            );
        if (!_mapping.valid())
            return;

        _view = reinterpret_cast<char*>
            (::MapViewOfFile(_mapping.get(), FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0));
        if (!_view)
            return;

        _length = file_size.QuadPart;
    }

    ~file_map()
    {
        if (_view)
            UnmapViewOfFile(_view);
    }

    bool valid() const
    {
        return (_view != nullptr);
    }

    const char * begin() const
    {
        return _view;
    }

    const char * end() const
    {
        return begin() + length();
    }

    unsigned long long length() const
    {
        return _length;
    }

private:    // ban copy
    file_map(const file_map&);
    file_map& operator=(const file_map&);

private:
    win32_file_handle   _file;
    win32_handle        _mapping;
    char*               _view;
    unsigned long long  _length;    // in bytes
};


unsigned long long count_char_using_memory_mapping(const std::string& filename, const char ch)
{
    unsigned long long char_count = 0;

    file_map view(filename);
    if (!view.valid())
        throw std::runtime_error("Can't create memory-mapping of file.");

    for (auto it = view.begin(); it != view.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it == ch)
        {
            char_count++;
        }
    }

    return char_count;
}


template <typename TestFunc>
void run_test(const char * message, TestFunc test, const std::string& filename, const char ch)
{
    const long long start = counter();
    const unsigned long long char_count = test(filename, ch);
    const long long finish = counter();
    print_time(start, finish, message);
    std::cout << "Count of \'" << ch << "\' : " << char_count << "\n\n";
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    static const int kExitOk = 0;
    static const int kExitError = 1;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << argv[0] << " <char> <filename>.\n";
        std::cerr << "Counts occurrences of ASCII character <char>\n";
        std::cerr << "in the <filename> file.\n\n";
        return kExitError;
    }

    const char ch = *(argv[1]);
    const std::string filename = argv[2];

    try
    {
        // Execute tests on THREE different files with the same content,
        // to avoid caching effects.
        // (file names have incremental number suffix).
        run_test("C <stdio.h> file (FILE*)", count_char_using_c_file, filename + "1", ch);
        run_test("Win32 file (CreateFile)", count_char_using_win32_file, filename + "2", ch);
        run_test("Win32 memory mapping", count_char_using_memory_mapping, filename + "3", ch);

        return kExitOk;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "\n*** ERROR: " << e.what() << '\n';
        return kExitError;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: To reduce syscall overhead, the `FILE` implementation is doing its own buffering. Nothing too magical about it.

Comment: As a quick note: If you perform back-to-back tests on the SAME file, the second test result will be skewed by file data/metadata caching.  Windows caches file data as does the disk controller hardware.  I could not tell from a quick read of the code whether the above statment applies, but it most often is the cause of things like this.

Comment: What happens if you increase the buffer size in `count_char_using_win32_file()`?

Comment: On my computer, `fopen` is the slowest after setting read buffer according to the claster size (4096)

Comment: @mr-c64 I remember reading another question on stackoverflow asking why fread is faster than ReadFile, it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290337/is-fwrite-faster-than-writefile-in-windows. The guy was reading it byte-by-byte, so of course fread was faster with its own buffering.

Comment: What tools are you using and what command lines are you using to build the benchmark?  I get rather different results depending on these details.

Comment: Is this really a duplicate of the "Is fwrite faster than WriteFile in windows?" question?  I wouldn't think that reading a file would have the same kind of interaction with flushing data that writing to a file does.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I used VS2010 SP1. The .exe was built from the IDE, in release build, with default settings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just ran some tests on my machine that shows that increasing the buffer size actually increases performance:

```
C <stdio.h> file (FILE*): 1431.93 ms
Bufsize: 0
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 2289.45 ms
Bufsize: 1024
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1714.5 ms
Bufsize: 2048
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1479.16 ms
Bufsize: 4096
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1328.25 ms
Bufsize: 8192
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1256.1 ms
Bufsize: 16384
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1223.54 ms
Bufsize: 32768
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1224.84 ms
Bufsize: 65536
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1212.4 ms
Bufsize: 131072
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1238.09 ms
Bufsize: 262144
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1209.2 ms
Bufsize: 524288
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1223.67 ms
Bufsize: 1048576
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 file (CreateFile): 1349.98 ms
Bufsize: 2097152
Count of 'x' : 3161882

Win32 memory mapping: 796.281 ms
Bufsize: 0
Count of 'x' : 3161882
```

Some steps in the Visual Studio 2012 debugger reveals that the buffer size of the FILE* method is 4096 bytes, at least on my machine. (And as others have already said it calls `ReadFile` too unless you are reading from a console.)

It is also interesting that big buffers marginally slow down the performance. Moving the `new` operator outside the test doesn't solve the issue either.

First the memory-mapped test was pretty slow for me because I ran it in Debug mode. I've updated all the results with the Release mode compilation. Memory mapping became the first.

Comment: The slow memory mapping is from running it in Debug mode from Visual Studio.  Build in Release mode.

Comment: Yeah I realised that.  I just noticed that if I build your program in Debug mode, I see the slow memory mapping on the same order as described in this answer.

Comment: I tried increasing buffer size for _both_ the Win32 `CreateFile()`/`ReadFile()` technique and the C `FILE*` `<stdio.h>` technique, and with 16KB buffers they are almost equivalent (memory mapping is still #1).

Comment: @paddy Yes, the results came really from a Debug build, updated.

Comment: @Mr.C64 It's really funny that the FILE* method uses larger internal buffer if you read larger blocks. I measured that 16K buffer in `C <stdio.h> file (FILE*)` mode went down to `1080.64 ms` that was again faster than then CreateFile method. Can you reproduce this?

Comment: @Csq: From my tests, with 16 KB read buffers for both `FILE*` and Win32 files, I get almost the same results, with some "fluctuations" of few tens of milliseconds in favor of one or the other.

Answer (score 9):

The fastest disk access I've ever attained was using `ReadFile`.  But I specifically opened the file with flags to meet my disk access and caching requirements.  If you just use it verbatim, the comparison is a little bit lame.

You should read up more on the function, as well as `CreateFile`.  You'll find you can read data in (multiples of) sector-sized blocks to sector-aligned memory.  Then you'll out-perform `fread`.

As others have said, `fread` is doing its own buffering.  Your buffering implementation with `ReadFile` still needs work.

Check out MSDN.  ALl the information is there.  Specifically, here:

- [File buffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Caching behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#caching_behavior)

Comment: I needed simple **sequential read access**, and opened the file with the `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` flag. Can you be more specific about your suggestion? Which flags should I use for optimal sequential reading access?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you are testing properly?
How are you accounting for disk position, seek time, file cacheing etc?

stdio and win32 are ultimately making the same calls to the Windows kernel to open the file.

mmap does things slightly differently, because it can reserve actually reading the data until it is used - if you have a fixed file size and performance matters, mmap is a good option

Answer (score 3):

When using memory mapped file, there is no need to copy the content of the file to your application - it is mapped in as a part of the virtual memory directly from the OS, so when you access the file-content, it just needs to be read straight into a page that goes into the mapped memory.

If you do the work correctly when using the Win32 API, it should be faster the the C stdio, as there is less overhead in the call. However, it's quite possible that you aren't getting the ideal balance between system call overhead and "too large a buffer, so the read takes longer than necessary". I would suggest you try with 4K or 8K (maybe even 32K) as a buffer in your Win32 API functionality - having a buffer-size that is a multiple of 4K is ideal, since a memory page is (typically) 4KB. Fewer calls to the API makes for less overhead, but you don't want to go too far.

[I did some testing like this on Linux the other day, and found similar results - and from my experience there: use different files for each test, otherwise your filesystem caching will help the tests that run later!].